# How to check if all the entries in columns of a matrix are equal?

Tags: matrix, expression-test

Assume we have the following matrix/tensor. How can I test if the column has the same element? 4-6 and 8-9 columns has the same element.

$ \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 \{2,3\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,3\} &
   \{2,3\} \\
 \{2,3\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,3\} &
   \{1,3\} \\
 \{1,3\} & \{2,4\} & \{1,3\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,3\} &
   \{2,3\} \\
 \{2,3\} & \{2,4\} & \{1,3\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{1,3\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,3\} &
   \{2,3\} \\
\end{array}\right)$

```
mat={{{2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 
   3}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 
   3}, {2, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 
   4}, {2, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 
   3}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 3}}};
```

I have tried this but it didn't work.

```
AllTrue[mat[[All, #]], SameQ] & /@ Range@10
```

Comment: `SameQ @@@ Transpose[mat]`?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: For larger matrices, integer arithmetic (performed in the reals) might be more performant: `{True, False}[[
 Unitize[
   (ConstantArray[1., Dimensions[A][[1]] - 1].Abs[
       Differences[A]]).ConstantArray[1., Dimensions[A][[3]]]
   ] + 1]]`.

Comment: My matrix is at most `10x90`

Comment: Then it's probably not worth the effort.